# Webforms: how to specify different content for a given masterpage

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

Given this markup in an ascx file :

```
        <div class="DocumentPara">
            <%#Eval("Content1").ToString%>
            <%#Eval("Content2").ToString%>
        </div>
```

Is there a syntax I can use to chose the display of "Content1" and "Content2" depending of which masterpage is calling?. I.e. :

```
        <div class="DocumentPara">
            <%#Eval("Content1").ToString%>
            <If masterpage1>
               <%#Eval("Content2").ToString%>
            </endIf>
            <If masterpage2>
               <%#Eval("Content3").ToString%>
            </endIf>
        </div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you dynamically changing masterpages the given page is using?

Comment: Yes. I have 2 masterpages. One for generating a Web page and the other one for generating a PDF with the ABCPDF module.

Comment: Your ascx code behind should have a property for which type of content and the page should set that property. Could be a enum. The page should know which master page it's using. In other word, the ascx shouldn't know which master page it's using, it's the page that should tell the ascx what to display. An other option would be to implement an interface on your master page and display the content based on the value of that interface.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks the_lotus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page's masterpage can be accessed via `Master` property, so to check for a specific masterpage in use you can do something like

```
if (this.Master is Master1Type)
```

The `if/else` syntax is also possible, and will look like this:

```
<% if (this.Master is Master1Type) { %>
    <%#Eval("Content2").ToString%>
<% }
else { %>
    <%#Eval("Content3").ToString%>
<% } %>
```

However that looks dirty to me, and having conditionals likes this inside the page markup is not a common practice. I would suggest defining a function in code behind to deal with masterpages logic, and output necessary value from the data item:

```
<%# GetContent(Container.DataItem) %>

protected string GetContent(object dataItem)
{
    if (this.Master is Master1Type)
    {
        return Eval("Content2");
    }
    // etc
}
```